# send/receive data using google proto buffer

Tags: c++, sockets

I need to design a socket which will listen to a port for incoming requests and send reply in response to these requests.
These sockets will also be responsible for sending data to port on some events ( which has nothing to do with data received mentioned above).

All this I have to do with google proto buffer.

Can anyone please suggest me with some good articles on these OR provide me help with this.

Comment: Well, google protocol buffers are really well documented themselves. Just go to https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use proto buffers with any networking library for C++. To send proto buffer just call `SerializeToArray` on your proto buffer object and send that array via network. If you receive object, use `ParseFromArray` function to deserialize your array back to proto buffer object.

boost asio could be used for that, see examples of servers and client [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html)

example (just for showing the concept):

```
class connection {
public:
    connection(const std::string& server, const std::string& port) 
        try 
            : is_ok_(false)
            , resolver_(ioservice_)
            , query_   (server, port)
            , socket_  (ioservice_)
        {
            GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERIFY_VERSION;
            asio::connect(socket_, resolver_.resolve(query_));
        } catch (...) { throw exception("Couldn't connect"); }

    ~connection() {
        socket_.close();
    }

    bool send_receive(Query* q, Response* r) {
        if (0 == q) return false;

        int query_length = q->ByteSize();
        std::vector<uint8_t> buf(query_length);

        if (false == q->SerializeToArray(&(buf[0]), query_length)) {
            std::cerr << "Couldn't serialize protobuf" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
        socket_.write_some(asio::buffer(buf));
        if (0 == r) return false;

        size_t s = socket_.read_some(asio::buffer(buf));
        r->ParseFromArray(&(buf[0]), (int)buf.size());
    }
private:
    boost::asio::io_service ioservice_;
    tcp::resolver           resolver_;
    tcp::resolver::query    query_;
    tcp::socket             socket_;
    bool                    is_ok_;
}
```